# Can Bucket fields be saved and used on other reports?

Tags: reporting, custom-field, bucket

Really not too much to this question - Can I create a bucket field, save it and use on other reports?

It's a bit of a pain having to create the same buckets all the time!

Kind Regards
Paul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a formula field on the object and it would be usable in all your reports on that object.

Before bucket fields this was the only option.  One of the big plusses for bucket fields was that admins no longer needed to create formula fields for this.  But the cons are that the same bucket does often need to be created on multiple reports.

You can always save a "template" with the bucket, and build new reports from there, to avoid recreating it.

Comment: reusable buckets would be so useful. even the template approach, which i've used, breaks down if the bucket definition changes after you've cloned the template into dozens of new reports. sigh

Comment: Yeah my problem is as above - the template is sooo temperamental. - I saw this on the message boards last night to get it introduced into SF - Surely it's an easy bit of coding for them to do. We are doing a massive merge of two orgz at the moment so I am not allowed to add any new fields etc so buckets have been so insanely helpful!